# How to relate with particular column in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am setting up a relation between two entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DEPT_ID")
    private String deptId;

    @Column(name = "DEPT_NAME")
    private String deptNAme;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DeptId")    
    private Department dept;

    @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
    private String empId;

    @Column(name = "EMP_NAME")
    private String empName;
}
```

The problem is that the table employee is related to the id of dept, I want to link it with deptId how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE

```
@JoinColumn(name = "DeptId" , referencedColumnName = "DEPT_ID") ;
```